# Reading QR Code natively from camera on Android device

Tags: android, android-studio, qr-code, google-vision

Can I make my phone camera natively read QR code and take necessary action without opening the specific application to read it? I don't want to open the application to read these QR codes.

I am developing an android application which requires the following functionality. Please let me know how I can do it.

Thanks,

Comment: Marcin, why did you remove some of the flags, In this question, they were actually correct.

Comment: You can try using this library as well : https://github.com/nipun-birla/QRReaderView

Answer (score 1):

This is the open source project to build QRCode reader with android camera
https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think using this method still I will have to open particular app to scan the QR code. I want my camera to automatically identify the QR code and take necessary action.

Comment: No. Just integrate the source code from this project into you android app project

Comment: And this library, may be out of date, check the google vision API

Answer (score 1):

What about native [**Mobile Vision API**](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/getting-started)? And here's a tut for  [**barcodes**](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/bar-codes/#0) by Google.

Answer (score 0):

Spinning on @Sid's answer, the Mobile Vision API is my preferred way to go. It contain Google's own barcode detector classes and I use it in production apps with great result.

If you like a simpler interface that just opens the camera and returns the QR-code (or barcode) upon detection, [this tutorial](https://www.varvet.com/blog/android-qr-code-reader-made-easy/) will probably be most useful. It contains all the stipped down classes you need as well.